# IndexError: Creating two lists from a text file

Tags: python, list, histogram

I cannot figure why when I run my code I get an IndexError saying my list is out of range. I run into the error at “ if x[1] == "strongly agree": “. I’ve went through my code many times and I don’t know how to fix..

Here is my code(not including import):

```
firstList = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
secondList = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

with open("surveyData.txt", 'r') as f:
answers = f.read().split('\n')
    
for x in answers:
x = x.split(',')
    
    if x[0] == "very happy":
       firstList[0] += 1
    elif x[0] == "happy":
       firstList[1] += 1
    elif x[0] == "neutral":
       firstList[2] += 1
    elif x[0] == "unhappy":
       firstList[3] += 1
    else:
       firstList[4] += 1 
    
    if x[1] == "strongly agree":
       secondList[0] += 1
    elif x[1] == "agree":
       secondList[1] += 1
    elif x[1] == "neutral":
       secondList[2] += 1
    elif x[1] == "disagree":
       secondList[3] += 1
    else:
       secondList[4] += 1

def showHistogram(dataList, bars):
plt.bars(bars, dataList)
plt.show()

question1_freq = ['very happy', ' happy', 'neutral', 'unhappy', 'very unhappy']
showHistogram(firstList, question1_freq)

question2_freq = ['strongly agree', 'agree', 'neutral', 'disagree', 'strongly disagree']
showHistogram(secondList, question2_freq)
```

Sample text file:
unhappy,strongly agree

very unhappy,strongly agree

happy,agree

neutral,strongly agree

happy,agree

very unhappy,strongly agree

neutral,strongly agree

very happy,disagree

Comment: Can you also add a sample of what surveyData.txt

Comment: @LeelaPrasad okay I’ll edit it

Comment: Are the each pair of survey data entries seperated by new line or space?

Comment: New line @LeelaPrasad

Comment: An empty new line between every entry?

Comment: No just a new line no empty lines between @LeelaPrasad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the below line and rest seems ok

```
answers = f.read().splitlines()
```

Comment: When I do that it says AttributeError: module ‘matplotlib.pyplot’ has no attribute ‘bars’

Comment: There is no `bars` method in pyplot. It should be `bar`. Change the code to `plt.bar`

Comment: I found what this error was talking about! I accidentally typed "plt.bars(.....)" instead of plt.bar. Thank you so much for your help! I love the profile pic btw. one of my fav animes